# LOG4J: Issue with Log Updates

Tags: log4j

I would like to ask for your assistance with an issue that we have in relation to the LOG4J tool.

Currently we have the following LOG4J configuration:

```
log4j.logger.amOfficeworks=INFO, apAVAGOASN
log4j.additivity.apAVAGOASN=false
log4j.appender.apAVAGOASN.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.apAVAGOASN.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p - %m%n
log4j.appender.apAVAGOASN.File=/apps/shared/logs/apAVAGOASN.log
log4j.appender.apAVAGOASN=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.apAVAGOASN.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.apAVAGOASN.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

Our production system is running in a cluster environment with 2 nodes. Each node contains the same configuration and is writing to a shared NAS folder (/apps/shared/logs).

If I understand the LOG4J tool, the root logger should always contain the most recent log entry. From what we observed in our system, the apAVAGOASN.log.1 sometimes contains the most updated entries and this is where we some issue. We currently have a monitoring in place to pre-alert our support team if the file apAVAGOASN.log does not update within a threshold of 15 minutes.

We have a hunch that this could be because both servers are writing in the same shared folder with the same file names and that this may be creating contentions (i don't know). Can someone shed some insight on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You certainly don't want to have both servers writing to the same log file names and locations. You should investigate using a folder per server.

Comment: Hi Mark,Thanks for your comment. Is there a restriction to this scenario when using LOG4J?

Comment: Since each server and its use of log4j is independent it has no knowledge of the files being shared. This isn't a log4j restriction but would apply to any writing of files with the same name to a shared directory from multiple servers (or the same apps on a single server writing to the same log files). Something at a higher level needs to coordinate the writes to avoid conflicts.